# Why does my "else" condition activate after completing the "if" condition (C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
    Console.WriteLine("Bent u een man of een vrouw?");

    string Geslacht = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Geslacht == "man")
    {
        double Totaal;
        double LengteMan;
        double H = 100;
        double N = 0.9;
        Console.WriteLine("Wat is uw lichaamslengte in cm?");
        LengteMan = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Totaal = (LengteMan - H) * N;
        Console.WriteLine("Uw ideale gewicht is " + Totaal + " Kilo");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    if (Geslacht == "vrouw")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestVrouw");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error");
    }
```

After the `if` condition has been completed, the console *still outputs* the `"error"`. Why is this happening and how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: are you looking for `else if (Geslacht == "vrouw")` - note, `else`?

Comment: In the case that `Geslacht == "man"`, the first `if` will be executed, but the `else` part of the second `if` will be executed, ouputting `error`.

Comment: You have *two* `if` conditions, which one are you referring to?  What *specifically* is happening, what do you expect to be happening, and why?

Comment: When learning to program, you need to learn to debug. Step through your code to see how it flows. Hit F10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `if ... else if ... else` pattern:

```
// Trim - let's be nice and tolerate leading / trailing spaces
string Geslacht = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

if (Geslacht == "man")
{
    // Either "man" (1st valid input)
}
else if (Geslacht == "vrouw")
{
    // Or "vrouw" (2nd valid input)   
}
else
{
    // All the other inputs are wrong ones (error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntaxis is wrong. You used an "if" instead of else if:

```
if (Geslacht == "man")
    {
        double Totaal;
        double LengteMan;
        double H = 100;
        double N = 0.9;
        Console.WriteLine("Wat is uw lichaamslengte in cm?");
        LengteMan = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Totaal = (LengteMan - H) * N;
        Console.WriteLine("Uw ideale gewicht is " + Totaal + " Kilo");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    else if (Geslacht == "vrouw")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestVrouw");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error");
    }
```

Comment: No, their syntax is correct, otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing the "Geslacht" string, you should not write two if, you must use else if instead if.

The correct code is :

```
Console.WriteLine("Bent u een man of een vrouw?");

    string Geslacht = Console.ReadLine();
    if (Geslacht == "man")
    {
       ....
    }
    else if (Geslacht == "vrouw")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestVrouw");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error");
    }
```